# What is happening on the second step of left mutation?

Tags: moduli-spaces, derived-categories, hilbert-schemes, fano-varieties

Let $X$ be a smooth Gushel-Mukai fourfold, whose semi-orthogonal decomposition is given by
$$D^b(X)=\langle\mathcal{K}u(X),\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{U}^{\vee}_X,\mathcal{O}_X(H),\mathcal{U}^{\vee}(H)\rangle$$, then we consider another semi-orthogonal decomposition by moving $\mathcal{O}_X(H),\mathcal{U}^{\vee}(H)$ to the left via Serre functor. Then we get
$$D^b(X)=\langle\mathcal{O}_X(-H),\mathcal{U},\mathcal{K}u(X),\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{U}^{\vee}_X\rangle.$$
Then we define projection functor $pr:D^b(X)\rightarrow\mathcal{K}u(X)$ as $\mathrm{R}_{\mathcal{U}_X}\circ\mathrm{R}_{\mathcal{O}_X(-H)}\circ\mathrm{L}_{\mathcal{O}_X}\circ\mathrm{L}_{\mathcal{U}^{\vee}_X}$

Now, let $C\subset X$ be a twisted cubic and we want to compute $pr(I_C(H))$. At the first step, $\mathrm{L}_{\mathcal{U}^{\vee}_X}(I_C(H))\cong(\mathrm{L}_{\mathcal{U}_X}I_C)\otimes\mathcal{O}_X(H)$ and by definition of left mutation, we have the following triangle
$$\mathrm{RHom}(\mathcal{U}_X,I_C)\otimes\mathcal{U}_X\rightarrow I_C\rightarrow\mathrm{L}_{\mathcal{U}_X}I_C.$$
To compute $\mathrm{RHom}(\mathcal{U}_X,I_C)$, we apply $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{U}_X,-)$ to the standard short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow I_C\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_C\rightarrow 0.$$
Then we get a long exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{U}_X,I_C)\rightarrow H^0(X,\mathcal{U}^{\vee}_X)\rightarrow H^0(X,\mathcal{U}^{\vee}_C)\rightarrow\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathcal{U},I_C)\rightarrow H^1(X,\mathcal{U}^{\vee}_X)=0.$$
It is clear that $H^0(X,\mathcal{U}^{\vee}_X)=k^5$ and $H^0(X,\mathcal{U}^{\vee}_C)=k^5$, thus $\mathrm{hom}(\mathcal{U}_X,I_C)=\mathrm{ext}^1(\mathcal{U}_X,I_C)\geq 0$ and it is not hard to show $\mathrm{ext}^i(\mathcal{U}_X,I_C)=0$ for $i\geq 2$. By geometry of Gushel-Mukai fourfold, $\mathrm{hom}(\mathcal{U},I_C)$ can only be $0$ or $1$, but I do not need it here, I only consider thoese twisted cubics such that $\mathrm{hom}(\mathcal{U}_X,I_C)=0$.

Thus, after first mutation, we get $I_C(H)$, now I perform the second mutation, which is $\mathrm{L}_{\mathcal{O}_X}I_C(H)$. Then I get an exact triangle
$$\mathrm{RHom}(\mathcal{O}_X,I_C(H))\otimes\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow I_C(H).$$

To compute $\mathrm{RHom}(\mathcal{O}_X,I_C(H))$, we apply $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{O}_X,-)$ to the short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow I_C(H)\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_X(H)\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_C(H)\rightarrow 0$$
we get a long exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{O}_X,I_C(H))\rightarrow H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(H))\rightarrow H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_C(H))\rightarrow\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_X,I_C(H))\rightarrow 0.$$
As $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(H))=k^9$ and $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_C(H))=k^4$. Thus $\mathrm{hom}(\mathcal{O}_X,I_C(H))=5$, since the hyperplane sections containing $\langle C\rangle\cong\mathbb{P}^3$ is of five dimensional.
Then we get a triangle
$$\mathcal{O}_X^5\xrightarrow{s} I_C(H)\rightarrow\mathrm{L}_{\mathcal{O}_X}I_C(H).$$
***Is the map $s$ surjective?*** I think it is not surjective, thus the image of $s$ is $I_D(H)$, where $D$ is the zero locus of $s$ containing $C$, ***but I have no clue what does $D$ look like. We only know $D$ is a surface, but I have difficulty to know what type of surface it is.***

Comment: Now, I am convinced myself that $h^0(I_C(H))=5$ since this space is all hyperplane section containing $C$, which is all hyperplane section containing $\langle C\rangle\cong\mathbb{P}^3$, which is five dimensional.

Comment: In the case of GM threefold $Y$, there is also a similar triangle $\mathcal{O}_Y^{4}\xrightarrow{s'}I_C(H)\rightarrow\mathrm{L}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}I_C(H)$, we can show the image of $s'$ is a curve $D$ containing $C$ and degree of $D$ is either $4$ or $3$.